# Peugeot 405 GLD 1993 1.9D NA What's the part numbers for the following?

Tags: parts, peugeot, servicing

I'm looking for anyone with information on these vehicles. As many people know, these 405's are becoming quite a desirable car nowadays, being a torquey, reliable workhorse. And, the 1.9 NA engines are extremely bulletproof, figuratively speaking. But, here's my question;

Does anyone know where I can get the part numbers, or does anyone have information on basic filters' part numbers? Fuel, Air and Oil filters are practically impossible to find, and even the most seasoned Peugeot dealers in the UK can't find out what I need. However, I was told that over in the US, these cars were popular as a small executive low-cost saloon/luxury car. No car parts specialist here in the UK can tell me about these cars. It's like trying to ask a stable-master about a breed of horse he's never seen before; impossible to get any useful information. I'm also curious as to what oil should be run, as I was told that many people use a slightly lower viscosity oil with these engines seeing as they're so old.

The old filters do NOT have any part numbers on them, and the engine code is too damaged to be read. I do not know where the VIN number is located on these vehicles either. I've only recently got hold of my 405. The service manual is also somewhat useless as there.... is none.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer, but it isn't, at least not directly... For the oil filter - there are remote kits available for some cars to put the filter in an easier place. If you find a remote kit that fits then you could also "pick" a suitable "newer" filter that would do the job. I got one years ago but not sure who made it - it was an aluminium sandwich with two ports for the engine and two hoses and a filter body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm you can still get the parts for this engine.

Mann is the original filter manufacturer and their part numbers are as follows:

- Air Filter: C33156
- Oil Filter: W7053 or (rarely) W712/8
- Fuel Filter: P716 or (rarely) P 725x
- Cabin Filter: CU2861

Just give those part numbers to any good motor factors and they will get them.

Peugeot will also be able to get any parts, you probably gave just got a lazy parts advisor, I have the same problem with my local one so I use the next furthest one away, whos advisor is a typical 'old school' ex mechanic.

I recently ordered a full head set which was in stock in the UK.

A lot of other manufacturers also use that engine, the only one I can think of is the LDV Pilot and obviously Citroen.

Although I can't understand why you can't find any filters, every parts site I've just visited has every filter in stock.

You also say you're in the UK so the VIN number will be in the V5 (log book), may be in the passenger side windscreen viewed from the outside, on a black and white sticker on one of the front door shuts, on the boot / tailgate bottom shut, under a flap in the carpet next to the drivers seat or on the front cross member/bonnet shut.